# Non-commutative concatenation of strings, keeping strings separate

Tags: string-manipulation

I'm using strings as symbolic notation for non-commutative linear algebra and need to be able to concatenate without losing ordering and without combining the strings (in order to apply rules I've defined), like this:

```
a = {"X","Y","Z"}

b = {"I","J","K"}

Command[a,b] -> {"X""I","Y""J","Z""K"}
Command[b,a] -> {"I""X","J""Y","K""Z"}
```

The closest I've gotten so far is the following:

```
stringJoin[x__String] := StringJoin[x]
SetAttributes[stringJoin, Listable]
n=stringJoin[a,b]
m=stringJoin[b,a]
```

Output: n = {"XI","YJ","ZK"} , m = {"IX","JY","KZ"}

Comment: Possible approach: `SetAttributes[CircleTimes, Listable];
Format[CircleTimes[a_, b_], StandardForm] := 
 DisplayForm@RowBox[{a, b}]`. Usage: `{"a", "b", "c"}\[CircleTimes]{"u", "v", "w"}`.

Comment: You can use `NonCommutativeMultiply`.